# Why does Ron have scars on his arms?

Tags: harry-potter

Over the course of their 'adventures' the trio has incurred many scars, below is a handy-dandy picture showing some of them:

[image: The scars of the Trios]<sup>Art by [dakotaaaa](http://dakotaaaa.tumblr.com/post/36023825287/the-trio-and-the-scars-they-got-along-the-way)</sup>

I have to admit though, I can remember Harry's and Hermione's but I can't for the life of me think of how he got those scars!

How did Ron get his scars?

Comment: Where did you get that picture from?

Comment: @Omega reddit I think?

Comment: Is this image canon? Are Ron's scars mentioned in the books?

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt: Well, yeah, in OotP it is mentioned that the brains did leave some scars on Ron. I'm not sure if they were ever removed though.

Comment: Ah, that explains it.  I thought it was the scars from his two splinching accidents.

Comment: Can someone tell me when Hermione got the Mudblood scar? I cannot recall...

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Pursuant to **Pureferrets**'s answer, I thought the explanation of why the scarring was so severe is interesting:

> [Ron] helped himself to a handful of Chocolate Frogs from the immense pile on his bedside cabinet, threw a few to Harry, Ginny and Neville and ripped off the wrapper of his own with his teeth. There were still deep welts on his forearms where the brain’s tentacles had wrapped around him. **According to Madam Pomfrey, thoughts could leave deeper scarring than almost anything else**, though since she had started applying copious amounts of Dr Ubbly’s Oblivious
>   Unction there seemed to have been some improvement.
>   <sub>*Order of the Phoenix* - page 746 - Bloomsbury - chapter 38, *The Second War Begins*</sub>

Ain't that the truth ...

Answer (score 37):

Ron got them at the Battle of the Ministry of Magic, when he was attacked by brains:

> *""Hey, Harry, there are brains in here, ha, ha, ha, isn't that weird, Harry?...Honest, Harry, they're are brains — look — Accio Brains!" The scene seemed momentarily frozen. Harry, Ginny, and Neville and each of the Death Eaters turned in spite of themselves to watch the top of the tank as a brain burst from the green liquid like a leaping fish...The moment they came in contact with his skin, the tentacles began wrapping themselves around Ron's arms like ropes..."Harry, it'll suffocate him!" screamed Ginny."*
> [Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Battle of the Ministry of Magic](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Thought)

Comment: "Accio Brains" - Wow, Ron's a *genius*.

Comment: @Kevin I think he'd been stupefied at the time.

Answer (score 23):

> "You can still see where those brains got hold of me in the Ministry, 
>   look," said Ron, shaking back his sleeves. ~HBP Chap. 11

So the brains definitely left a lasting impression

Answer (score -1):

If you read the book, he got them in the Ministry of Magic after being attacked by brains. It's later mentioned in Half Blood Prince when Ron shows them to try and seem impressive next to Harry, probably to impress Hermione. If you only watched the movies, you won't see this.

Comment: This answer, while being a good one, doesn't add any details to the other answers of this question.

Answer (score -3):

And in the movies when hermoine apparates them into the woods ron gets caught in the event of it and gets those scars sorry if that description doesn't make much sense.

Comment: You could improve this answer by editing it to be more specific about which movie -- and which part of that movie -- you're referring to here.