# Why does Hermione have this scar?

Tags: harry-potter

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28054/why-does-ron-have-scars-on-his-arms) contains the following image, and asks why Ron has a series of scars on his arms.

[image]

That's great and all, but I'm left confused;

**When does Hermione get a scar reading 'Mudblood' on her arm?**

Comment: So you *wanna know how she got these scars*?

Comment: Um...Am I dumb to ask what Ron's are?

Comment: @kaine No, but the question in which it is asked is linked to in my question, in quite literally the first two words.

Comment: oh hah... sorry

Comment: @kaine Ron's scars are from the brains which wrapped around him in the Department of Mysteries. "Thoughts scar deeper than anything else"

Answer (score 37, accepted):

She gets the scar from Bellatrix Lestrange in book 7 while she is captive at house Malfoy.

In the movie this occurs in the following scene:

According to [Harry Potter Wikia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Scar):

> Hermione has Mudblood written on her arm, a cut on her neck and many bites, all of them made by Bellatrix Lestrange, in 1998, at the Malfoy Manor

As Checked in the book and also as commented by Valorum:

> Why shouldn’t I?” said Hermione. “Mudblood, and proud of it! I’ve got no higher position under this new order than you have, Griphook! It was me they chose to torture, back at the Malfoys!” As she spoke, she pulled aside the neck of the dressing gown to reveal the **thin cut Bellatrix had made, scarlet against her throat**.

Comment: Just beat me to it!  +1

Comment: gotta be quick these days ;-)

Comment: short delay in network and the instant I click post, the update appears...

Comment: If I remember rightly though the "Mudblood" scar is purely an invention of the movie, the book doesn't mention it.

Comment: @DavidS, you're probably right. The book only mentions she gets tortured and untill this day bears the scars.

Comment: The sole mention of hermione's wounds are *"“Why shouldn’t I?” said Hermione. “Mudblood, and proud of it! I’ve got no
higher position under this new order than you have, Griphook! It was me they
chose to torture, back at the Malfoys!”
As she spoke, she pulled aside the neck of the dressing gown **to reveal the
thin cut Bellatrix had made, scarlet against her throat.**"*

Comment: Bites? Bellatrix bit Hermione??

Answer (score 13):

Bellatrix carves this into her while they were imprisoned with Olivander and the Lovegoods in Deathly Hollows Part 1:

Answer (score 4):

The book didn't mention the carving. In the movie, Bellatrix gives her that scar with the knife that killed Dobby.

Answer (score 1):

Hermione never gets the word 'Mudblood' carved into her, but she does receive a cut on her throat from Bellatrix's knife. Trust me, I read thoroughly.

Comment: Some citations would help, so other people can look it up for themselves, no matter how much they trust you.

Answer (score 0):

Hermione only gets the Mudblood scar in the movie. The only mention of a scar in the book is the cut on her neck that she sustains after Bellatrix threatens to slit her throat.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Answer (score -1):

Hermione, Harry, and Ron steal a sword or something from Bellatrix. Bellatrix gets suspicious, asks Hermione who lied and Bellatrix didn't believe her so she carved "Mudblood" on Hermione's arm.

Comment: How did Ron get his scar?

Comment: From the brains in the Ministry. Book 5.

Answer (score -1):

Some old woman dressed in a wig, I believe her name was Bellatrix carved "Mudblood" on Hermione's left arm and didn't carve anything on her right.