# Is Dumbledore Ron in the future?

Tags: harry-potter, time-travel, albus-dumbledore, ron-weasley

They both love Bertie Botts, they both have long fingers, share a left-leg injury, like Chocolate Frog Cards, and have naturally red hair.

Comment: I didn't know that Ron had a left-leg injury (he has arm injury per http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/28054/4918 , and an apparition accident affecting his hand). Do you have a reference for that? I also didn't know that Professor Dumbledore had naturally red hair: he already has grey hair in Philosopher's Stone.

Comment: The thing is, Ron isn’t *smart* enough to be Dumbledore. Not to mention that Dumbledore’s whole family history is well-known among those old enough to remember.

Comment: @b_jonas The Whomping Willow broke his leg in book three I think

Answer (score 15):

False. Confirmed by J.K. Rowling herself on Twitter.

> **Samantha:** Dear @jk_rowling: Ron is a time-traveling Dumbledore -- fact or theory?
>
> **J.K. Rowling:** False theory.

https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/649913211521794048